# Laravel Select only specific columns while eagerloading polymorphic relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is not working the response contains all the columns, but I want to return only `id`column from comments table.
I'm using Laravel 5.4

**Tables**
notifications table

```
content_type

content_id
```

comments table

```
id

body
```

**Models**

Notification.php

```
public function content() {
        return $this->morphTo('content');
    }
```

NotificationController.php

```
public function getNavbarNotifications(Request $request) {
        $notifications = $request->user()->notifications()->latest()->limit(5)->get();
        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            $notification->load(['content' => function ($query){
                $query->select('id');
            }]);
        }
        return $notifications;
    }
```

**Response from the NotificationController**

[image: [enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
return $this->morphTo('content')->select(array('id'));
```

in your Notification.php.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the question is about the eagerloading so I want to do that while eagerloading the relationship, The way you suggested it will fetch the id every time but I want to fetch it based on some condition in `NotificationController` while eagerloading it in the `foreach` loop.